# Multiple file attachment, show files attached, remove file button option.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need script for file attachment in HTML input type file. While files attached in input file then have to **show the file names** also **show the remove file button** option beside the file name. Then add more file button option with multiple file attachment need.

Comment: first of all, you have to show us what you tried so far! If you have completly no clue on how to achieve things like that, please google first and check out some tutorials.. there are also many plugins out there which will solve this problem for you..

Comment: Try: [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com)

Comment: Thanks for the dropzone.js suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//jQuery plugin
(function( $ ) {
   
   $.fn.uploader = function( options ) {
     var settings = $.extend({
       MessageAreaText: "No files selected.",
       MessageAreaTextWithFiles: "File List:",
       DefaultErrorMessage: "Unable to open this file.",
       BadTypeErrorMessage: "We cannot accept this file type at this time.",
       acceptedFileTypes: ['pdf', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'tif', 'tiff', 'png', 'xps', 'doc', 'docx',
        'fax', 'wmp', 'ico', 'txt', 'cs', 'rtf', 'xls', 'xlsx']
     }, options );
  
     var uploadId = 1;
     //update the messaging 
      $('.file-uploader__message-area p').text(options.MessageAreaText || settings.MessageAreaText);
     
     //create and add the file list and the hidden input list
     var fileList = $('<ul class="file-list"></ul>');
     var hiddenInputs = $('<div class="hidden-inputs hidden"></div>');
     $('.file-uploader__message-area').after(fileList);
     $('.file-list').after(hiddenInputs);
     
    //when choosing a file, add the name to the list and copy the file input into the hidden inputs
     $('.file-chooser__input').on('change', function(){
        var file = $('.file-chooser__input').val();
        var fileName = (file.match(/([^\\\/]+)$/)[0]);

       //clear any error condition
       $('.file-chooser').removeClass('error');
       $('.error-message').remove();
       
       //validate the file
       var check = checkFile(fileName);
       if(check === "valid") {
         
         // move the 'real' one to hidden list 
         $('.hidden-inputs').append($('.file-chooser__input')); 
       
         //insert a clone after the hiddens (copy the event handlers too)
         $('.file-chooser').append($('.file-chooser__input').clone({ withDataAndEvents: true})); 
       
         //add the name and a remove button to the file-list
         $('.file-list').append('<li style="display: none;"><span class="file-list__name">' + fileName + '</span><button class="removal-button" data-uploadid="'+ uploadId +'"></button></li>');
         $('.file-list').find("li:last").show(800);
        
         //removal button handler
         $('.removal-button').on('click', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
         
           //remove the corresponding hidden input
           $('.hidden-inputs input[data-uploadid="'+ $(this).data('uploadid') +'"]').remove(); 
         
           //remove the name from file-list that corresponds to the button clicked
           $(this).parent().hide("puff").delay(10).queue(function(){$(this).remove();});
           
           //if the list is now empty, change the text back 
           if($('.file-list li').length === 0) {
             $('.file-uploader__message-area').text(options.MessageAreaText || settings.MessageAreaText);
           }
         });
       
         //so the event handler works on the new "real" one
         $('.hidden-inputs .file-chooser__input').removeClass('file-chooser__input').attr('data-uploadId', uploadId); 
       
         //update the message area
         $('.file-uploader__message-area').text(options.MessageAreaTextWithFiles || settings.MessageAreaTextWithFiles);
         
         uploadId++;
         
       } else {
         //indicate that the file is not ok
         $('.file-chooser').addClass("error");
         var errorText = options.DefaultErrorMessage || settings.DefaultErrorMessage;
         
         if(check === "badFileName") {
           errorText = options.BadTypeErrorMessage || settings.BadTypeErrorMessage;
         }
         
         $('.file-chooser__input').after('<p class="error-message">'+ errorText +'</p>');
       }
     });
     
     var checkFile = function(fileName) {
       var accepted          = "invalid",
           acceptedFileTypes = this.acceptedFileTypes || settings.acceptedFileTypes,
           regex;

       for ( var i = 0; i < acceptedFileTypes.length; i++ ) {
         regex = new RegExp("\\." + acceptedFileTypes[i] + "$", "i");

         if ( regex.test(fileName) ) {
           accepted = "valid";
           break;
         } else {
           accepted = "badFileName";
         }
       }

       return accepted;
    };
  }; 
}( jQuery ));

//init 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fileUploader').uploader({
    MessageAreaText: "No files selected. Please select a file."
  });
});
```

```css
.file-uploader {
  background-color: #dbefe9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #242424;
}

.file-uploader__message-area {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #377a65;
}

.file-list {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.file-list__name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.file-list li {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-left: .5em;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.removal-button {
  width: 20%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #d65d38;
  color: white;
}
.removal-button::before {
  content: "X";
}
.removal-button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.file-chooser {
  padding: 1em;
  transition: background-color 1s, height 1s;
}
.file-chooser p {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.file-uploader {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
.file-uploader * {
  display: block;
}
.file-uploader input[type=submit] {
  margin-top: 2em;
  float: right;
}

.file-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.file-list__name {
  max-width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.removal-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.file-chooser {
  width: 90%;
  margin: .5em auto;
}

.file-chooser__input {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.file-uploader__submit-button {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #72bfa7;
  color: white;
}
.file-uploader__submit-button:hover {
  background-color: #a7d7c8;
}

.file-list li:after, .file-uploader:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hidden input {
  display: none;
}

.error {
  background-color: #d65d38;
  color: white;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="file-uploader" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="file-uploader__message-area">
    <p>Select a file to upload</p>
  </div>
  <div class="file-chooser">
    <input class="file-chooser__input" type="file">
  </div>
  <input class="file-uploader__submit-button" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```